# MVC3 Telerik Treeview Add HTML Elements(Button) to each node

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, treeview, telerik

I am using Telerik treeview in MVC3 Razor view  to display tree structured information. I would like to Add a set of Buttons/Links (Edit,Create,Details) to each node in the tree.
I tried the following but the actionlink does not get displayed.The model is a List

```
     @(Html.Telerik().TreeView()
    .Name("my-treeview")
    .BindTo(Model, (currentItem,  tree) =>
    {
        currentItem.Text = tree.Name;
        currentItem.Encoded = false;
        currentItem.Expanded = true;
        currentItem.Value = tree.val;
        currentItem.Enabled = true;
        currentItem.Template.InlineTemplate =
                           @<text>

                                 @Ajax.ActionLink("Test", "Test", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "testid" });
                           </text>;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This won't work indeed. Set the `Text` property to the required HTML value. And make sure `Encoded` is set to `false`.